# How to know if I read everything from a non-blocking socket

Tags: c, sockets

I have a non-blocking connection socket I accepted:

I have a non-blocking socket connection, and after receiving a packet of data, I attempt to read more using recv.

```c
struct sockaddr accepted_address;
socklen_t accepted_address_size = sizeof(accepted_address);

int fd = accept(server_fd, &accepted_address, &accepted_address_size);
make_nonblocking(fd);

... // wait when socket is ready to give me data

char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
int  used = 0;

while (true) {
    int bytes_received = recv(fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0);
    if (bytes_received > 0) { /* OK */ }
    else if (bytes_received < 0) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
            /* Should wait for more data, BUT I WILL WAIT INDEFINITELY!!! */
        } else {
            /* Handle error */
        }
    } else {
        /* EOF, OK, Process received data */
    }
}
```

The problem arises when the first recv call retrieves the entire message, but subsequent calls result in `errno == EAGAIN`, leading to an indefinite wait for more data that will never arrive.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256248/what-is-blocking-behaviour-at-eof)
this behavior is expected.

My question is:
**How can I reliably determine that I have received the entire message if the second call to recv won't give me EOF but instead returns EAGAIN, leaving me waiting indefinitely?**

Comment: It doesn’t leave you waiting indefinitely. You’re in non-blocking mode.

Comment: If there is nothing left to read, then stop reading. Come back to it later, preferably after `select()` or `(e)poll()` or other similar mechanism has told you that more data is waiting to be read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I reliably determine that I have received the entire message ...

TCP has no concept of a message, it is only a byte stream. This means to determine the end of the message, you need first to understand what a message is in terms of the application protocol you are implementing, like for example a line ending with `\n`, a fixed size message, or some payload prefixed by its size. Based on this, then you can check if the data received so far represents only part of a message, a full message, or even more than one message.

Comment: And this requirement applies whether you use blocking or non-blocking sockets.

Comment: So there's no way, I'll have to parse byte stream while I'm getting it, and determine that depending on the contents... sigh... Thank you!

Comment: @ViacheslavRadko how else would you expect to do it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
I don't know many applications where the stream nature of TCP is used, people usually talk by sending whole message at once.
So I expected some kind of marker, like: "part 1/3; size 123/1024 bytes", so I could wait until I get all three parts, and then start parsing this buffer.

I implemented parsing partially received data, it's not perfect but it somehow works, so it's ok. But I just didn't want to do it real bad.

Comment: @ViacheslavRadko There is no such marker at the TCP level, it has to be handled in the data itself. Hence the need to parse the data while you are receiving it.